# Tracking all the links in Outbound Email

Tags: 2013-sp1, outbound-email

We have to enable tracking on all the links in Outbound email (newsletters).

As per the documentation [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Doutbound%2520track&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1418641283825&currentQuery=outbound%2520track&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-693BC2E5-82E4-41E9-8545-C707200E6087&query=outbound%2520track&scope=&filename=GUID-693BC2E5-82E4-41E9-8545-C707200E6087.xml&docid=GUID-693BC2E5-82E4-41E9-8545-C707200E6087&inner_id=&tid=5afe65e8-43d6-4d84-9f23-5cc9a21661cb&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false): setting up Outbound E-mail Post-Processing TBB's parameter to "Yes" should convert all the links in the email to trackable links - but it is not working for me - I might be missing some settings.

I have updated the TBB's parameter, and tried putting a static link in Newsletter PT, like `<a href="http://www.google.com/"> Google Link </a>`, but it is not getting converted to trackable link.

However, `GetLinkTrackingURL` method is working fine. The following link: `<a href="@@GetLinkTrackingURL('http://www.google.com','Google')@@">Google search</a>`,

gets converted to trackable link,

`http://mywebsite/EmailTracking/Tracking.aspx?a=L&p=$Am9_0PPGhVRpVEkxUb5lUOx2XdMn5lUiAusCXmnCYfU2D4LoZ5rUohxDhbgO9VGQ`

Is there any other configuration that needs to be done to make all the links in outbound emails as trackable?

**Update 1:**

Following in the Newsletter compound template that is being used:

```
<CompoundTemplate xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.3/CompoundTemplate">
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:12-46-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Outbound E-mail Pre-processing" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="uuid:81C64ADD-4698-4C2E-AB87-473EC0711DCE" />
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:12-19-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Extract Components from Page" />
    <TemplateParameters></TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:12-885-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Newsletter" />
    <TemplateParameters></TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:12-44-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Outbound E-mail Post-processing" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="uuid:4F031745-E95E-4D3F-90D7-B859CF3FB2E7">
        <TrackLinks>Yes</TrackLinks>
      </Parameters>
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:12-32-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Default Finish Actions" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="uuid:C695849C-4EFA-4F72-B8F2-68170C9F86C3" />
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
</CompoundTemplate>
```

"Newsletter" TBB contains the link which is not getting converted into trackable link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your output needs to be valid XHTML -- or at least able to be parsed as XML.

If you enable logging within Template Builder, I'm sure you will see a message to that effect...

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, just checked the Template Builder, "OutboundEmail: Cannot Track Links: ensure template is valid XHTML."

Answer (score 0):

What does your compound template chain look like? Which TBB writes the output and where is the post-processing TBB located? Could you dump the contents of the compound page template here and indicate which TBB writes the output?

Update: your compound template looks fine to me; could you try Peter Kjaer's solution and temporarily replace the contents of your DWT TBB "Newsletter" with only

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"> Google Link </a>
```

and see if this gets replaced properly?

Comment: Added the compound template chain, "Yes" parameter has been set for "Post processing" tbb